# Intel SSD Toolbox options are disabled for SSD when Intel firmware update works fine

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, trim

I configured my BIOS to use JBOD instead of RAID because RAID does not support TRIM for SSDs.
My laptop BIOS does not have any option for SMART or AHCI, it's just JBOD or RAID0 or RAID1.

Bootable disk with Intel Firmware Update Tool detected my SSDs and reported that they have latest firmware.
I hoped that Windows 7 will detect them too, but I don't see any indication of it other than option to use it as ReadyBoost, which is also available if I insert flash card.

When I installed and started Intel SSD Toolbox it shows me drive and size, but does not show firmware version or any other information. Also it has all helpful SSD options disabled.

When I check fsutil DisableDeleteNotify it gives me 0, so TRIM sending is not disabled.

I want to be sure that SSD gets those TRIM commands and with SSD Toolbox not working I suspect that it does not get them.

I use latest RAID driver from Toshiba, which is dated 2006.

Is it possible to make Intel SSD Toolbox to work on my system ?

Is there another way to determine if my Windows behaves not destructively for SSD, i.e. sending TRIM and reallocating sectors for wear levelling ?

I have Intel 945 Express Chiset, ICH7, 82801G controller.

Comment: Toshiba Qosmio G35-AV660

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intel SSD Toolbox does not work with drives that are part of a RAID array (see the [FAQ](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http://download.intel.com/support/ssdc/hpssd/sb/intel_ssd_toolbox_frequently_asked_questions.pdf&ei=smHlTrfgPKORsAKW3fiCBg&usg=AFQjCNHsPtBeCX7CcYZ6oWd3-CNRJERcHA&sig2=a4n1diJcnyp1DAmNyxeE9g)).  It must not like the JBOD setting in your BIOS, either.  Is there no way to have your SSDs operate independently?

Comment: My laptop does not have external SATA port, only USB 2.0 ports. BIOS has only 3 options JBOD, RAID0,RAID1. Would it help if I buy eSATA Card like this: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16839328027&nm_mc=OTC-Froogle&cm_mmc=OTC-Froogle-_-PC+Cards/PCMCIA+Add-on+Cards-_-Syba-_-39328027 ? I just worry that it will not solve the problem of detection by Intel SSD Toolbox, which is the only problem I have.